# How to prove that test 1 produces more results than test 2?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

If I have 2 tests applied on a set of data, both tests either produce a result ( assume = 1) or no result ( NA , assume = 0 ). Is there a way to prove that test 1 produce more results than test 2 with significant results? For example the results below shows that test 1 is better than test 2 but how to prove the significance part ? Is there other test than using t-test?

```
Test1 , test 2
1, 0 
1, 0 
0, 0, 
1, 1
0 , 0 
0 ,1
1, ,1
1, 0 
1, 0
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using somewhat confusing terminology, since "test" and "assume" have their own meaning in the statistics world. Do you want to investigate if there are more "1"s in the left column?

Comment: Yes , and if that is significance

Comment: Not "other than using t-test," because 1/0 variable is not suitable for t-test. Try searching [comparing two proportions](https://www.google.com/search?q=comparing+two+proportions) or [chi-square test](https://www.google.com/search?q=two-way+chi+square+test).

Comment: Please remove [tag:t-test] from your tags. It doesn't seem to be relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply testing for a difference in proportions. In large samples, you can use a normal approximation to the sample proportion in the two groups and calculate a simple proportions test for the differences in proportions. In small sample sizes, this approximation will lead the test to being very poorly calibrated. If that happens, I would suggest using [permutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29) or some other resampling based statistic.

If the results are *paired* such as one blood sample being used in two diagnostic assays, then you can test for a difference in proportions using [McNemar's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test).

Lastly, if your goal is to compare diagnostic accuracy, you can use [Cohen's Kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) to measure (and make inference) on the interrater agreement between two tests, then calculate the sensitivity and specificity of the two tests and report which one has better recall.

These distinctions are very important to the problem description. I suggest making any revisions with background and objective as necessary to your post.